# How to Access parentViewController's methods and properties

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I've been searching for a solution for this problem but I couldn't solve it!
I tried

```
mapViewController = (MapViewController*)self.parentViewController;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you expecting parentViewController to return?  Are you implementing view controller containment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this ..

in your class .h file

make a member variable

```
@interface SomeClass: NSObject
{

 UIViewController *controller;
}
```

when you initialize the class make it controller to self ...that way it will work the same way as

```
SomeClass *class = [[SomeClass alloc]init];
class.controller = self;
```

now you can use the parent properties and methods..However you will still need to typecast it to `(MapViewController*)controller` so that it autocompletes its methods.